# Tilting for quadric

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Kapranov showed that for a quadric $Q$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ there is a tilting bundle. For example if we consider a vector space $V$ of dimension $n=4$ and $\mathbb{P}(V)$ then the tilting bundle is $\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)\oplus \sum_{+}(-2)\oplus\sum_{-}(-2)$. Now $\omega^{\vee}_Q=\mathcal{O}(2)$ so what is $\mathrm{Ext}^k(\mathcal{T},\mathcal{T}\otimes \mathcal{O}(2))$? This should be zero for $k>0$...

Comment: The case $n = 4$ is quite simple since $Q = P^1\times P^1$ and $\Sigma_\pm$ are $O(1,0)$ and $O(0,1)$ (up to a twist). So, it is very easy to compute the endomorphism algebra.

Comment: In general you can compute $Ext$'s by Borel--Bott--Weil (all the sheaves are equivariant).